# Email with logs from Cloudwatch & lambda

Tags: email, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have lambda function which gets triggered by sqs, runs some logic and produces logs on cloudwatch.
I want to send email to users in case specific error logs are captured on cloudwatch.

I have created a cloudwatch metric but i am bit clueless how to send a email with log in it. I can use cloudwatch metric to create an alarm but that alarm won't provide log details.

what needs to be done once i have filtered the logs?